How to Merge Duplicate Rows and Sum Numeric Values in Power BI When Cleaning Sales Data from Multiple Regions?
I have taken up this course "Data Transformation in Power BI" on a website called 'data camp', and here I am stuck in this task where I am supposed to clean the sales data given to me by using transpose and unpivot features and find out what was the largest sales value transacted with a company in one month.
here is a link to datacamp to download/view the file: (https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/production/repositories/6048/datasets/Exercises+and+Datasources/data-transformation-in-power-bi.zip)
file path: Datasets> Sales_1997



emp ID
region
company name
year
month
total sales




1
Eastern
Antonio Moreno
1997
April
456


3
Eastern
Antonio Moreno
1997
Sept
521


5
Southern
Antonio Moreno
1997
Sept
541


9
Western
Around the Horn
1997
Jan
410


8
Northern
Around the Horn
1997
May
102


1
Southern
Around the Horn
1997
Jan
132


6
Eastern
Around the Horn
1997
Jan
245



I first demoted my headers and transposed my table. then I individually merged the rows and transposed them back to their original form. here is my result with the code:
=Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Transposed Table", {{"Column3", type text},{"Column4", type text}}, "en-US"), {"Column3", "Column4"}, Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None), "Merged")



company name
year
month
total sales




Antonio Moreno
1997
April
456


Antonio Moreno Antonio Moreno
1997 1997
Sept Sept
521 541


Around the Horn,Around the Horn,Around the Horn
1997 1997 1997
Jan Jan Jan
410 132 245


Around the Horn
1997
May
231



Assuming that I remove the 2nd column ('region'), What I need is to get the following result:



company name
year
month
total sales




Antonio Moreno
1997
April
456


Antonio Moreno
1997
Sept
1062


Around the Horn
1997
Jan
787


Around the Horn
1997
May
231



If I could get a help over this problem that'd be really great. thanks!

Your expected results table and description seem inconsistent. You write "LARGEST sales value transacted" yet your table is showing the "TOTAL sales value transacted. Which do you mean?  Or am I misinterpreting what you write?

Also, is it a requirement to use Transpose and Unpivot to solve this? Or is that just a suggestion? In general, either would be more easily solved using the Table.Group method.

@RonRosenfeld yes, ultimately I am supposed to find out LARGEST sales value transacted from my total sales column. And no that is not a requirement as long as I identify the highest sales value that was made with a company in a single month.

Please see my response which, I believe, solves your entire problem.

@RonRosenfeld the correct answer is sale of 14989.8 (with no mention of the company name) and the answer that I have achieved after correction is company: QUICK-Stop sales:15913.67

I am away from the computer now. I will take a look later today.

@RonRosenfeld sure! looking forward to your kind assistance.

Take a look at my edited answer. The process results in showing 14,989.80 with a label characterizing it but no mention of a company.

The correct answer is sale of 14989.8
You have supplied the wrong data-set to obtain this answer.
Given the zipped file you linked to:

Open the 1_1_unpivot_transpose.pbix file with Power BI
This will open two Tables:



Home => Transform Data will open the Power Query Editor

Remove the top row (only has the years information)

Select Column 1 and Unpivot other columns

Group by Column 1 and Attribute

Aggregate by Sum of Value


The above produces a table like this:


At this point you have several options. Since you want to show just the single value, I suggest:

Close and Apply

Select a Card visual

Select the Total Sales/Month for the data value

Select Maximum for the aggregation (drop down next to the Data field in the setup for the visual)

Format the value to show the full number.




you can try to use the group by function in PQ

